# How to delete a file using Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++

I want to delete file from my program. Trying to use this function but still fail;

```
#include<stdio.h>
DeleteFile(L"c:\c.png");
```

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Escape the `\`;

```
DeleteFile(L"c:\\c.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

`DeleteFile` works.

Try,

```
DeleteFile("c:\\\c.png"); // 2 slashes.
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it!  I forgot the double backward slashes :)

```
DeleteFile(L"c:\\c");
```

Comment: Hmm. Good. Anyways dont reply to your own qustions rather add a comment.